# Saving files from an email in PHP

Tags: php

I'm writing a fetcher of emails from IMAP. I've written my code so that it will look for BOTH attachments and inline images.

Everything works great, but I'm having trouble with the `file_put_contents` part where the content of the attachment is saved.

I've just put `$object['attachment']` as kind of a best guess around what it should be, because I don't know how to obtain this from the array/s.

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

if ($emails) {

  rsort($emails);

  foreach($emails as $n)  {

    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$n);

    foreach($structure->parts AS $object) {

      if (strtolower($object->disposition) == "attachment") {

        foreach ($object->dparameters AS $object2) {
          if(strtolower($object2->attribute) == "filename")
            $filename = $object2->value;
        }
        //file_put_contents($filename, base64_decode($object['attachment']));
      }

      foreach($object->parts AS $object2) {
        if (strtolower($object2->disposition) == "inline") {

          foreach ($object2->dparameters AS $object3) {
            if(strtolower($object3->attribute) == "filename")
              $filename = $object3->value;
          }
          //file_put_contents($filename, base64_decode($object['attachment']));
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Omkaar.K That's about _sending_ attachments, not receiving them.

Comment: Ok then, @duskwuff, use this: https://stuporglue.org/recieve-e-mail-and-save-attachments-with-a-php-script/

Comment: @duskwuff thanks for the link, I'm using this instead!